# Beautifulsoup: exclude unwanted parts

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I realise it's probably a very specific question but I'm struggling to get rid of some parts of text I get using the code below. I need a plain article text which I locate by finding "p" tags under 'class':'mol-para-with-font'. Somehow I get lots of other stuff like author's byline, date stamp, and most importantly text from adverts on the page. Examining html I cannot see them containing the same 'class':'mol-para-with-font' so I'm puzzled (or maybe I've been staring at it for too long...). I know there are lots of html gurus here so I'll be grateful for your help.

My code:

```
import requests
import translitcodec
import codecs

def get_text(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

    # delete unwanted tags:
    for s in soup(['figure', 'script', 'style', 'table']):
        s.decompose()

    article_soup = [s.get_text(separator="\n", strip=True) for s in soup.find_all( ['p', {'class':'mol-para-with-font'}])]    
    article = '\n'.join(article_soup)

    text = codecs.encode(article, 'translit/one').encode('ascii', 'replace') #replace traslit with ascii
    text = u"{}".format(text) #encode to unicode
    print text

url = 'http://www.dailymail.co.uk/femail/article-4703718/How-Alexander-McQueen-Kate-s-royal-tours.html'
get_text(url)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only `'p'`-s with `class="mol-para-with-font"` ?
This will give it to you:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
url = 'http://www.dailymail.co.uk/femail/article-4703718/How-Alexander-McQueen-Kate-s-royal-tours.html'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BS(r.content, "lxml")

for i in soup.find_all('p', class_='mol-para-with-font'):
    print(i.text)
```

Comment: Thank you. I can see now I was carried away with too many brackets etc...:)